Error 404 with Pagination on Custom Query
I have a custom query with a while loop on my page.php, to display multiple post types I have created using ACF. But my pagination does not seem to work, it always shows the Error 404 page.
Here is the Custom Query:
global $wp_query;

            $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

            $args = array_merge($wp_query->query, array(
                'post_type' => array('post', 'event', 'project'),
                'posts_per_page' => 8,
                'paged' => $paged
            ));


            $mainfeed_query = new WP_Query($args);

            while ($mainfeed_query->have_posts()) {
                $mainfeed_query->the_post();
                ?>

Here are the pagination links I tried adding after wp_reset_postdata(); :
<?php
            echo paginate_links(array(
                'total' => $mainfeed_query->max_num_pages,
                'current' => $paged,
                'prev_text' => __('« Previous'),
                'next_text' => __('Next »'),
            ));
            ?>

Where could I be going wrong? Thanks

what is the output of the pagination link? send that link

<a class="page-numbers" href="http://meponetv1.local/page/2/">2</a>
<a class="page-numbers" href="http://meponetv1.local/page/3/">3</a>
I was wondering if the problem is with the permalinks but I couldn't find a fix for it.
